# Add 30 calendar dates to a date column

Tags: sql-server, dateadd, weekday

Hope you are doing well.

I use Microsoft SQL server Mgt studios 18.

I have a table which has a Date column to which i need to add 30 working days (holidays are not considered, have to exclude only Saturday and Sunday) and have the resulted date in another column named altered Date in the same table.

I am going to use the script/query as a trigger on update. So i cannot create and use function.

Is there any other simple way that i can do this?

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: So you have two columns? One called date and another altered date? What is the difference between these two columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to add one or more tags for the tools/languages you use to your question (I added sql-server for you).

Comment: Use a calendar table

Answer (score 0):

So this is a simple way to insert dates into a table and skip Saturday's and Sundays. If you need it to start at a specific day, you can simply add a parameter in place of GETDATE(); If you need additional help, comment and I can edit this answer.

```
    CREATE TABLE YOURTABLENAME (
      MyDate Date
    );

    DECLARE @i int;
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE @i < 30
    begin
    SET @i = @i + 1;
    IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day, @i, GETDATE())) BETWEEN 2 and 6
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YOURTABLENAME VALUES(DATEADD(day, @i, GETDATE()))
    END
    END
    SELECT * FROM YOURTABLENAME
```